# how to avoid header and footer html code when getting data from ajax in zend framework?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, zend-framework2

I am having some problem with the ajax . I want to get image name only using ajax but I am getting  header and footer content instead of image name..

here is my code.

controller file

```
  public function deleteimageAction() {

         $id = (int) $this->params()->fromRoute('id', 0);
         $image = $_POST['image'];

    return $image;

    }
```

and my ajax-

```
 $('.delete').click(function(e){
        var imageName=$(this).attr('data');
        var id=$(this).attr('id');
        $.ajax({
            url:'/test/zend/public/business/deleteimage/'+id,
            type: 'POST',
            data:{id:id,image:imageName,},
            success: function (data) {

                alert('Success : please check console')
                console.log(data);
            },
            error:function(data) {
                alert('Error : please check console')
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

and getting the following result in the console -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>ZF2 Skeleton Application</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <!-- Le styles -->
        <link href="/test/zend/public/css/bootstrap.min.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="/test/zend/public/css/style.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="/test/zend/public/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="/test/zend/public/images/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon">
        <!-- Scripts -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/test/zend/public/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/test/zend/public/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!--[if lt IE 9]><script type="text/javascript" src="/test/zend/public/js/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body>
            </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you get the page contents, then you can't be calling the correct controller. Can you add _all_ the relevant code? Like where you defined your routes etc.

Comment: Your controller method doesn't take any arguments, but you're adding the `id` value to the URL as well as posting it as post-parameter?

Comment: i removed post id from ajax but i am having  issue with the header and footer html code that i getting as a result instead of image name.. can you please help me to avoid header and footer html code and get only image name..

Comment: To repeat myself: Can you add **_all_** the relevant code? Like where you defined your routes etc. The above code isn't enough for us to get a clear picture. Also, when you say _"i removed post id from ajax"_, what do you mean? Removed it from the URL, from the `data: {...}` object or both?

Comment: Enable `JsonViewStrategy` in your config + make sure controller extends AbstractRestController (or similar) instead of AbstractActionController. (google both if you haven't used these before to get their documentation). Also, instead of 'return ViewModel' or 'return [ //data ]' you must `return JsonModel([ data ])`

Comment: Also, judging from the relative paths in the src attributes you haven't got an `.htaccess` file setup correctly. You should not have to include `/test/zend/public` in your source attributes

Comment: its done. thanku very much. :)

Comment: @Dev5 excellent. Could you post the solution you created as an answer and mark it as such? Could help out others in the future.

Answer (score 0):

```php
public function deleteimageAction() {
    $id = (int) $this->params()->fromRoute('id', 0);
    $image = $_POST['image'];
    echo $image;
    exit();
}
```

Comment: You may want to explain your changes too.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.